# SQLite error: CursorIndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

[image: StackTrace While running the following code in android]

Code:
It shows CursorIndexOutOfBoundException.
I am running the following code and I am trying to save the value in database and extract it compare it after getting the columnindex from the database.

```
SQLiteDatabase db= openOrCreateDatabase("tryitdb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String sql= "create table if not exists tabletry(score int)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.close();
        tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getsc();
            }
        });
    };
    public void getsc() {
        SQLiteDatabase db= openOrCreateDatabase("tryitdb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String sql= "select * from tabletry";
        Cursor c1= db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        if(c1!=null && c1.getCount()>0){
            int i1= c1.getColumnIndex("score");
            String score= c1.getString(i1);
            int old= Integer.valueOf(score);
            int str= Integer.valueOf(et1.getText().toString());
            if(old>=str){
                tv1.setText(old);
            }
            else{
                tv1.setText(str);
            }
        }
        else{
            init();
        }

    }
    public void init() {
        String s=et1.getText().toString();
        SQLiteDatabase db= openOrCreateDatabase("tryitdb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String string= "insert into tabletry values(?)";
        Object[] oa= new Object[1];
        oa[0] = s;
        db.execSQL(string,oa);
        db.close();
        tv1.setText(s);
    }
```

It shows me error on the line 
            String score= c1.getString(i1);
Please suggest a fix. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you try to access column values from a cursor, you'll have to move it to point to a valid row. Use one of the `moveTo...()` methods for that.

For example, change

```
Cursor c1= db.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(c1!=null && c1.getCount()>0){
    int i1= c1.getColumnIndex("score");
    String score= c1.getString(i1);
```

to

```
Cursor c1= db.rawQuery(sql, null);
if(c1.moveToFirst()){
    int i1= c1.getColumnIndex("score");
    String score= c1.getString(i1);
```

`rawQuery()` won't return a `null` so checking for it is not really necessary, and `moveToFirst()` will return `false` if the cursor doesn't point to a valid row after the move so you can remove the `getCount()` check, too.

Answer (score 3):

You should move the cursor to first record and then try retrieving values.

```
 if(c1!=null && c1.getCount()>0){
       ***c1.moveToFirst();***
        int i1= c1.getColumnIndex("score");
        String score= c1.getString(i1);
```